# easiest way to create bulk insert script from the result of a select query?

Tags: mysql

I'm archiving some data from one table to another. the rows i want to move i find using query like this

```
select * from T where completed =1 or deleted =1;
```

would like to have the results of this create bulk insert statement like

```
INSERT INTO testdb . archive_t(id, name, userid, etc) Values
(1,dave,25,...),
(2,bob,26,...),
(3,fred,33,...)
```

what would be the best way of going about generating that.

thanks

Comment: Both tables are in the same db? and do both tables having the same structure?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to dump in DML format using mysqldump. You can skip the table creation statements.

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --skip-disable-keys --no-create-info 
  --where "completed=1 or deleted=1" testdb archive_t
```

Comment: Ok but my database is an Amazon Aurora mysql db so i dont have local connection/command line. thats why was looking for a way to build it using existing database connection (ie running select query and using that output for the bulk insert)

Comment: So add the `--host` option and connect to your Aurora instance. You can run the mysqldump client over a network connection.